# Hide login username from WinSCP title bar

Tags: sftp, winscp

Upon connecting via `SFTP` to a remote system, `WinSCP` GUI displays the connection details on the titlebar of the application, as :

```
user@<system_ip> - WinSCP
```

I was wondering if there is a way to hide this information on the titlebar. I checked in the `Environment` preference options, but did not notice anything with a casual glance. There is an option in `Window` section to hide the path currently being navigated to on the remote system, but it does not remove the connection details. `Toolbar` options did not have anything either.

A check at https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation did not yield the information I was looking for.

Is there a way for this information to be hidden?

I am using the latest `WinSCP` version on `Windows 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What WinSCP GUI shows in the title is the name of the session.

If you open an ad-hoc session (without saving it as a stored site on the Login dialog), WinSCP indeed generates an implicit name with a format `user@host`.

But if you [save your session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login#new_site) on Login dialog, you can name it any way you like.

You can also [rename an opened session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_tabs#renaming) – But you would have to do that every time.

If you want to prevent showing connection details on the Login dialog too, you can create a [desktop shortcut to the site](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login#shortcuts) to skip the Login dialog completely.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate it.